# Reading different formats in the Excel (XLS) data from Apache POI 3.2

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to read an XLS (2007 format) file using JDK 1.4 and Apache POI 3.2 .
I have few rows in the file already which are TEXT formatted (RIght click-> Format cells -> Text).

I added few more rows in the file manually, without any text formatting, Assuming the format for the newly added rows will be RAW.

POI is not able to read the rows which were added later.
It can only read them if the newly added rows are also formatted to TEXT.

The code looks like as follows:

```
HSSFSheet sheet = workBook.getSheetAt(sheetno);
int rowStart =  sheet.getFirstRowNum();
//int rowEnd = sheet.getLastRowNum();
int rowEnd =    sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
for (int rowNum = rowStart; rowNum <= rowEnd; rowNum++)
        {
            HSSFRow row = (HSSFRow) sheet.getRow(rowNum);
            Vector cellStoreVector=new Vector();
            int current = 0, next = 1;

            for (int colNum = row.getFirstCellNum(); colNum < row.getLastCellNum(); colNum++)
            {
                HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell) row.getCell(colNum);             
                currentCell = cell.getColumnIndex();
                current = cell.getColumnIndex();
                if (current < next)
                {
                    cellStoreVector.addElement(cell);
                }
                else 
                {
                    int loop = current - next;
                    for (int k = 0; k < loop + 1; k++)
                    {
                        cellStoreVector.addElement("");
                        next = next + 1;
                    }
                }
                next = next + 1;                                        
            }
      }
```

Things I've tried so far:

1) making use of a RowIterator object and then using a while loop to iterate.

```
Iterator rowIter = sheet.rowIterator();
while(rowIter.hasNext()) - Results in the same no. of rows being iterated.
```

2) Making use of

```
 sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows(); and
 sheet.getLastRowNum();- Results in the same no. of rows being iterated.
```

Has anyone faced similar issues with the Excel file before? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Arihant

Comment: AFAIK POI provides Excel 2007+ support from version 3.7.

Comment: POI 3.2 is almost 5 years old now, is there a reason why you're not using a more recent version?

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza - I want to run it for XLS only, So don't need the latest POI.
@ Gagravarr - The SAP Portal makes use of JDK 1.4, so need to have a downgraded version of POI.